# How to make clojure functions private for current namespace?

Tags: syntax, clojure

I came across this form recently:

```clj
(def ^:private -ns- *ns*)
```

- Is this how you make the functions in current file private to the namespace?
- What other type of access restrictions can be applied using this method?

Answer (score 1):

The `:private` metadata key is used to control the accessibility of vars. You can declare a private function using [`defn-`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4743) e.g.

```
(defn- foo [x] x)
```

Comment: `defn-` is just a macro that is a shortcut to using this valid code:  `(defn ^:private my-func [] ...`  ... either one works.

Answer (score 0):

There are no other access restrictions that can be applied via metadata.

Even this restriction is only surface level (the var is marked as private and the namespace will omit it from some calls). However, you can still directly access the var if you know it exists.